# Using context.drawImage() with a MediaStream

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, redux, webrtc

I'm new to React and I am building an app that takes screen grabs from a MediaStream. Based on what I've seen, the best way to do that is to draw it onto a canvas element using the `context.drawImage()` method, passing in the HTMLVideoElement as an argument. Here's what my action creator looks like:

```
const RecordImage = function(video, canvas, encoder) {
   if(!encoder) {
       encoder = new GifReadWrite.Encoder()
       encoder.setRepeat(0)
       encoder.setDelay(100)
       encoder.start()
   }
   const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
   context.drawImage(video, 0, 0)
   encoder.addFrame(context)
   return {
       type:       RECORD_IMAGE,
       payload:    encoder
   }
}
```

This worked in the past because the RecordImage action was being called from the same component that housed the `<video />` and `<canvas />` element, and I could pass them in like so:

```
takePic(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.RecordImage(this.video, this.canvas, this.props.encoder)
}
...
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <video 
                ref         = { video => this.video = video } 
                width       = { this.props.constraints.video.width } 
                height      = { this.props.constraints.video.height } 
                autoPlay    = "true" 
            />
            <canvas 
                ref         = { canvas => this.canvas = canvas }
                width       = { this.props.constraints.video.width } 
                height      = { this.props.constraints.video.height } 
            />
            <button onClick = { this.takePic }>Take Picture</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

However, I would like to house the "Take Picture" button in a different component. This is a problem because now I don't know how to access the `<video />` and `<canvas />` elements from a sibling component. Normally I would store the arguments I need as part of the state, but the `drawImage()` method needs to use the HTML elements themselves. I've heard it's a bad idea to store DOM elements in the state, so what would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @stefan-van-de-vooren for setting me on the right path! My situation was complicated by the child components using Redux connect, so getting them to work required some additional setup.

First, set up the parent component to call one child from the other:

```
setMedia(pic) {
    return this.control.getWrappedInstance().setMedia(pic)
}
getPicture() {
    return this.display.getWrappedInstance().getPicture()
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setMedia( this.getPicture() )
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <DisplayContainer ref= { display => this.display = display } />
            <ControlContainer ref= { control => this.control = control } />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Because Redux `connect` returns a higher order component, we need to use `getWrappedInstance()` to gain access to the child functions. Next, we need to enable `getWrappedInstance()` in our child components by telling `connect` to use refs. Also, we will set up our child functions.

DisplayContainer:

```
getPicture() {
   return this.video
}
...
render() {
   return ( <video ref= { video => this.video = video } /> )
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, { withRef: true })(Display)
```

ControlContainer:

```
setMedia(pic) {
    this.setState({ media: pic })
}
takePic(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.RecordImage(this.state.media, this.canvas, this.props.encoder)
}
...
render() {
    return(
       <button onClick= { this.takePic }>Take Picture</button>
       <canvas ref= { canvas => this.canvas = canvas } />
    )
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, { withRef: true })(Control)
```

The action creator remains the same:

```
const RecordImage = function(video, canvas, encoder) {
   if(!encoder) {
      encoder = new GifReadWrite.Encoder()
      encoder.setRepeat(0)
      encoder.setDelay(100)
      encoder.start()
   }
   const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
   context.drawImage(video, 0, 0)
   encoder.addFrame(context)
   return {
      type:       RECORD_IMAGE,
      payload:    encoder
   }
}
```

I should note, we are using refs quite a bit here. It is necessary in this case because the `context.drawImage()` needs the actual `<video />` element in order to work. However refs are sometimes considered an anti-pattern, and it is worth considering if there is a better approach. Read this article for more information: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs

A better solution would be to grab the image directly from the MediaStream. There is an experimental `grabFrame()` method that does just that, but as of Feb 2018, there is limited browser support. https://prod.mdn.moz.works/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageCapture/grabFrame

Answer (score 0):

In React it is possible to directly call a function on one of your components.
You could add a 'getPicture' function in your video component which returns the video element?

Your video component:

```
getPicture() {
    return this.video
}
...
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <video 
                ref         = { video => this.video = video } 
                width       = { this.props.constraints.video.width } 
                height      = { this.props.constraints.video.height } 
                autoPlay    = "true" 
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

The picture button component could look something like this:

```
takePic() {
    const element = this.props.getPic
    const encoder = new GifReadWrite.Encoder()
   encoder.setRepeat(0)
   encoder.setDelay(100)
   encoder.start()

   const canvas = document.createElement("canvas") 
   canvas.width = element.offsetWidth
   canvas.height = element.offsetHeight
   canvas.drawImage(video, 0, 0)
   encoder.addFrame(context)
   return {
       type:       RECORD_IMAGE,
       payload:    encoder
   }
}

...
render() {
    return (
        <button onClick = { () => this.takePic() }>Take Picture</button>
    )
}
```

And then a parent component to bind the button and the video component:

```
getPicture() {
    return this.video.getPicture()
}
...
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <VideoElement ref="video => this.video = video"/>
            <TakePictureButton getPic="() => this.getPicture()" />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm not sure how the draw function works, but you get the idea